# rownumber in insert into

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, oracle12c, row-number

I wanted to insert the row number in one of the column. But since `row_number()` is a **window**(**analytic** *proper to Oracle*) **function** which can be used only for select statement is there any other way to insert row number.

eg :

```
INSERT INTO prnr (pm,GEG_ID,ET_ID,fzg_id,nr,id)
VALUES(p_gpm_id,master_rec.geg_id,master_rec.et_id,
       master_rec.fzg_id,row_number() over (partition by master_rec.geg_id));
```

i want to use this insert statement in a procudure.

Comment: What is `master_rec`?  This code has problems beyond the `row_number()`.  Sample data and desired results would be helpful.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER` used to give the incremental numbers to the set of records based on the `ORDER BY` clause in the `OVER` clause. What are you expecting with `row_number() over (partition by master_rec.geg_id)` and again asking the same question as asked by Gordon, What is `master_rec`?

Answer (score 1):

Try refactoring your code to an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```sql
INSERT INTO prnr (pm, GEG_ID, ET_ID, fzg_id, nr, id)
SELECT p_gpm_id, geg_id, et_id, fzg_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY geg_id),
       -- some 6th column here...
FROM master_rec;
```

Comment: master_Rec is not a table but it is variable selected from some other table. a select statement isnt possible in this case. so is there any alternative for row_number() in this case of simple insert into

Comment: Please address Gordon's comment under your question, which I strongly second.

Answer (score 0):

If your aim is just simply generating a sequential integer value(*as described within the comment*), for the `id` column, then recreate existing `id` column with `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY` option such as

```
ALTER TABLE prnr DROP COLUMN id;
ALTER TABLE prnr ADD id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY;
```